# Why does _kbhit() only work once in a C program?

Tags: c++, c

I just wrote this little program, that should wait for the user to type something before printing each line, but it only works for the first _kbhit(), afterwards it does not wait anymore. Why's that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Canada\n");
    while ( _kbhit() == 0 );

    printf("is\n");
    while ( _kbhit() == 0 );

    printf("great!");
    while ( _kbhit() == 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

There's no information in the [function reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that _kbhit() only works once in a program.

Comment: It says right in the documentation you linked how to consume the keystroke.

Comment: But it does not say that you **have** to consume it.

Comment: One does not have to consume the keystroke, could leave it there and simple exit.  But as the doc says "If the function returns a nonzero value, a keystroke is waiting in the buffer."  By not consuming it, the keystroke is still a penny waiting for change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it doesn't say it that explicitly in that documentation page, you have to consume the keystroke (with `getch` or `getche`), otherwise `_kbhit` will still see it. Call `_getch` after the while-loop before the next one:

```
while(_kbhit() == 0);
_getch();
// _kbhit can now be called again
```

Answer (score 2):

Kninnug's answer will work, but it raises processor ussage needlessly, because while loop must execute over and over.
Much better solution is to just use

```
_getch();
```

In that case program will wait for user to press any button without wasting processor time